# Migrating a national website to an international version

Tags: migration, domains, seo, international

I have a Persian web service (online diaries): 31shab.com and it's been operating successfully for a year.

We've decided to create an international version of this and rebrand it to 31nights (meaning of 31shab in English). So I registered the domain 31nights.com and I want it to be multilingual.

So I want to know what is the best way to do this migration successfully, i.e.:

- I want to move 31shab.com to 31nights.com/fa/ permanently (fa means Persian) in a way that doesn't ruin my SEO and Google ranking, etc.
- What's the best way to structure languages? Folders or subdomains or ... ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to do 301 redirect for all the old pages to the new page of your new website by doing so Google will pass on all the link equity from old Urls to new once and your rankings & traffic wont get affected; you may see some fluctuation in first two months then it will be all right.

You can create sub folders for different countries or languages that is more better for SEO than having sub-domain.

Answer (score 0):

When you move from 31shab.com to 31nights.com/fa/, be sure to redirect all the old pages to their new relative location with a HTTP 301 ('Moved Permanently'), so that search crawlers and search engine bots "know" that you have actually moved it to a new and permanent location, and that it is not just gone or temporarily moved

Comment: I've done this once, moved sallar.ir to sallar.me, and everything moved successfully, but since this one is a single language to multi language website, I had doubts. so the concept remains the same. right?

Comment: Yeah, i can't se why there should be a big difference. I think subfolders in fine for language custom versions of the site, no reason to have dedicated subdomains